How to ommit cmdlet parameter
I have a question about cmdlets parameters.
Let say I have a function like this
function Do-Something
{
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $fParam
   )

  get-result -clParam $fParam
}

Then I call this function like this
$var = "somedata"
Do-Something -fParam $var

Code executed without erros (if $var has the appropriate data type, of course)
When I call function like this
$var = $null #or Variable var does not defined at all
Do-Something -fParam $var

I gets error, something about "incorrect data type for -clParam" or "-clParam can't be empty" and so on.
To avoid such an errors as far as I understand my function should test if -fParam is empty or not:
function Do-Something
{
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $fParam
   )
  if($fParam -ne $Null)
  {    
    get-result -clParam $fParam #if fParam is defined, run cmdlet with param
  }
  else
  {
   get-result  #if fParam isn't define or $Null, run cmdlet without param
  }
}

My question is: Is it possible to avoid such bulky structures? Is there a way to force the cmdlet to independently determine that an empty variable was passed to the parameter and therefore be executed without the parameter?

Does this answer your question: How to check if a PowerShell optional argument was set by caller?

As an aside: $null be on the left side of the equality comparison

Read up onn default values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.4 some times a well chosen default value can do the workyou are trying to do here.

Two general approaches:

Allow the caller to pass $null, handle it inside the function, or
Use splatting at the callsite!

To allow the caller to pass $null as an argument, use the [AllowNull()] attribute decorator:
function Do-Something
{
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [AllowNull()]
    $fParam
   )

  if ($null -ne $fParam) {
    Get-Result -clParam $fParam
  }
  else {
    Get-Result 
  }
}

An alternative is to use splatting at the callsite - splatting allows us to conditionally prepare the parameter arguments we want to pass to the function in a dictionary, like so:
$fArg = $null
$argTable = @{}

if ($null -ne $fArg) {
  $argTable['fParam'] = $fArg
}

# if `$fArg` was $null, then `$argTable` will be empty and no parameter arguments will be passed
Do-Something @argTable

